# Using copy_if function from first vector to another vector copy numbers which multiples of n

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

> Create a vector with 20 random numbers. Copy numbers, that are multiples of n in another B vector. Input n manually.
>
> Example `A` vector
>
> `8,9,6,4,2,6,8,6,10,101,10,10,101,10,10,101,6,6,12,14`.
>
> `n=4`. `B` vector will be `8,4,8,12`.

My program does not print B vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int> creating()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(rand()%9+1);
    }
    return vec;
}

void print(vector<int> &vec)
{
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        cout<<vec[i]<<"   ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

bool predicate(int n)
{
    int k;
    cin>>k;
    return (n %k== 0 );
}

vector<int> copying(vector<int> &A)
{
    vector<int> B(20); //int n; cin>>n;
    copy_if(A.begin(), A.end(), B.end(), predicate());
    return B;
}

int main ()
{
    vector<int> vec=creating();
    print(vec);
    vector<int> B=copying(vec);
    print(B);
}
```

Comment: I have to copy from a vector to other vector numbers, which multiplies to n.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should probably have `copy_if(A.begin(), A.end(), std::back_inserter(B), predicate);` but your predicate will read `k` from the user every time it's executed - that is, one time for each element in `A`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: `rand() % x` does not give good distributions – suppose this does not matter, tough. I have some doublts if limiting to [1;9] is in the sense of your task seeing e. g. 101 in the sample vector...

Comment: `vector<int> B(20);` creates a vector with already 20 elements in, all 0. Suppose you rather wanted to have `std::vector<int> B; B.reserve(20)`? Copying to `end()` in any case will write beyond the vector's range and result in undefined behaviour. See @TedLyngmo's comment on how to solve. Alternatively: `std::vector<int> B(20);` as is, copying to `B.begin()` (!) and (as you don't necessarily have 20 elements in) `resize` to `begin` subtracted from result of `copy_if` which returns an iterator to one past the last element.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have to copy numbers in other vector, but print function does not print anything

Comment: @ნინოწინამძღვრიშვილი Did you look at any of the answers you got?

Answer (score 0):

Print function works perfectly fine, but copy_if receiving predicate, which is called for every element from vector A.
So `cin >> k` called 20 times.

It's better to call it once:

```cpp
int n;
cin >> n;
```

and then use inside predicate:

```cpp
bool predicate(int element, int divider){
   return (element % divider == 0);
}
```

Since `copy_if` only acceping predicate with signature `bool Name(Type element)` with no custom data, we should capture `n` with lambda:

```cpp
int n;
cin>>n;

copy_if(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), [=](int em){
   return predicate(em, n);
});
```

Note also
`vector<int> B(20);` creates new vector with 20 elements preallocated, means it will contain 20 elements from the start. And copy_if should use `B.begin()` instead `B.end()`.

If you want to ADD elements instead of copy, initialize B without preallocated elements and use `back_inserter(B)` instead `B.begin()`

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` function assumes there are 20 elements in the `vector`. Since you don't know how many `copy_if` will put in it, don't assume that.

```
void print(const std::vector<int>& vec){
    // for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) std::cout << vec[i] << ' ';
    // or:
    for (int v : vec) std::cout << v << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Your predicate currently reads user input every time it's invoked. Instead, make it keep the value for `k` by making it into a functor:

```
struct predicate {
    int k;
    bool operator()(int n) const {
        return n % k == 0;
    }
};
```

You could use a lambda instead:
`[=](int n){ return n % k == 0; }`

Your `copy_if` tries to add elements to the end of the `vector` which makes it have *undefined behavior*. You need a [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
#include <iterator>

std::vector<int> copying(const std::vector<int>& A){
    std::vector<int> B; // create it empty
    std::copy_if(A.begin(), A.end(), std::back_inserter(B), predicate{4});
    return B;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/chnvrEKdr)